# Django migrate unique field between models with data

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

Let's assume I have this models structure:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(unique=True, null=False, default=uuid4)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

I would like to merge UserProfile into User model, like this:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    uuid = models.UUIDField(unique=True, null=False, default=uuid4)
```

Most important thing is to migrate existing `uuid` from `UserProfile` model to new  `User.uuid` (unique) field. How should that be managed in django > 1.7 migrations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add the `uuid` field to the `User` model. Create a migration.

Then, create a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) and add a [RunPython](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.RunPython) operation to call a function that copies the data from the old to the new models. Something like:

```
def copy_uuid(apps, schema_editor):
    User = apps.get_model("myapp", "User")

    # loop, or...
    User.objects.update(uuid=F("userprofile__uuid"))

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = []

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(copy_uuid),
    ]
```

Once you've migrated and are sure that everything worked, you can delete the `UserProfile` model in another migration.